# Configuring filebeat to get delta data from log file

Tags: logstash, filebeat

I am using filebeat to stream log data to logstash but whenever I append new lines to the log file filebeat sends the whole data to logstash. Now I want if new data(delta data) is added to my log file only that data be streamed to the logstash. Is there some configuration which I need to take care of in filebeat.yml. My current filebeat config looks like-

```
filebeat:
  prospectors:
    -
      paths:
        - /Users/yogi/dev-tools/elastic_search/access_log/*.log
      input_type: log
      document_type: app_log
      ignore_older: 10m
      scan_frequency: 10s
output:
  logstash:
    hosts: ["localhost:5000"]
    bulk_max_size: 1024
  console:
    pretty: true
shipper:
logging:
  files:
    rotateeverybytes: 10485760 # = 10MB
```

Comment: What is your current Filebeat configuration?

Comment: Updated it in the description.